# Asp.net Identity email validation not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

in my web application i use asp.net identity for managing users
this is my register method for registering users

```
   [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(UserRegisterJson userRegisterJson)
    {
        IUserManagement userManagement = new UserManagement();
        var user = userManagement.GetUserFromJson(userRegisterJson);

        var identityResult = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, userRegisterJson.Password);

        if (!identityResult.Succeeded)
        {
            //return error
        }else{
            return Ok(true);
        }


    }
```

i send user info as json format in request body the problem is when user email equals *"example" or "example@example." or "example@exam ple.com"*

**identityResult.Succeeded return false**

but when user email *equals "example@example"*

**identityResult.Succeeded return true**.

my question is why email equals "example@example"

**identityResult.Succeeded return true?**

Comment: How are you validating the user email.

Comment: i have a class in my project it have a static method receive  Identity Result as parameter and then return error if identityResult.Succeeded return false,  but identityResult.Succeeded return true if email equals "example@example"

Comment: How are you validating the user email before creating user. client side? server side? Do you have any validation attributes on your model `UserRegisterJson` ? None of this can be extracted from your question so there isn't much to go on to help you.

Comment: i have no validation for user email both client side and server side before creating user,Although validating email in client side is good approach,if asp.net identity can validate email in several state why it can't validate an email such as "example@example"?

Comment: What version of Identity are you using

Comment: Asp.net identity version 2.2.1

Comment: Debug your code and check the UserValidator in the UserManager. If you're using Owin to inject the UserManager context, it should be populated correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [source code of UserValidator for that verison (v2.2.1)](https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/UserValidator.cs), the following method was being called in side of the `UserManager.CreateAsync`.

```
// make sure email is not empty, valid, and unique
private async Task ValidateEmailAsync(TUser user, List<string> errors)
{
    var email = await Manager.GetEmailStore().GetEmailAsync(user).WithCurrentCulture();
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email))
    {
        errors.Add(String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, Resources.PropertyTooShort, "Email"));
        return;
    }
    try
    {
        var m = new MailAddress(email);
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        errors.Add(String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, Resources.InvalidEmail, email));
        return;
    }
    var owner = await Manager.FindByEmailAsync(email).WithCurrentCulture();
    if (owner != null && !EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default.Equals(owner.Id, user.Id))
    {
        errors.Add(String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, Resources.DuplicateEmail, email));
    }
}
```

As you can see it is trying to create a `MailAddress` object using the email address provided. If the address is not in a valid format it should fail.

Given what ever format they used I created a unit test to verify the examples you provided.

```
[DataDrivenTestMethod]
[DataRow("example")]
[DataRow("example@example.")]
[DataRow("example@exam ple.com")]
[DataRow("example@example")]
public void ValidateEmailAddress(string email) {
    var m = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(email);
    Assert.IsNotNull(m);
}
```

The following results were returned

```
Result Message: 
Assert.IsTrue failed. 

DataRow: email: example
Summary: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

DataRow: email: example@exam ple.com
Summary: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

`example` and `example@exam ple.com` are not considered valid email address according to their logic.

I would suggest you try to perform you own email validation on the model before creating a new user